# Image with different dimensions?

Tags: android, flutter

android studio 3.6

In android app I use one image with different dimensions. I put image in the next folders:

```
drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi
```

Nice. It's work fine.

Now what about flutter app. Is I also need to create different folders for every image's dimension?

P.S. I need this image for android and iOS version

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the D[eclaring resolution-aware image assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware). You can create folders based on the resolution and add images to it.

[image: Resolution Aware Image Loading]

> The main asset is assumed to correspond to a resolution of 1.0. For
>   example, consider the following asset layout for an image named
>   my_icon.png:
>
> ```
> .../my_icon.png
> .../2.0x/my_icon.png
> .../3.0x/my_icon.png
> ```
>
> On devices with a device pixel ratio of 1.8, the asset
>   .../2.0x/my_icon.png would be chosen. For a device pixel ratio of 2.7,
>   the asset .../3.0x/my_icon.png would be chosen.

Reference [Assets and Images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

For an Android App created using Flutter, You can still use these folders as shown below for varying screen densities

[image]

Comment: But I need this image also for iOS version